# Map http params from http link

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have this incoming request that I want to map:

```
http://some_domain.com?key=value&t5052&key=value&key=value
```

I have this Spring configuration:

Endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, value = "/v1/notification")
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotifications(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, Object> keyValuePairs) {
     .....
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Spring convert config:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "org.rest.api.*", "org.plugin.service", "org.plugin.transactions.factory" })
@EntityScan("org.plugin.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.plugin.service")
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter);
        converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(
                ((XmlMapper) createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.xml()))
                        .enable(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION)));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json())));
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        builder.indentOutput(true);
        builder.modules(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
        builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        builder.defaultUseWrapper(false);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

But for some reason the values are not matched:

Here is the log file:

https://pastebin.com/GsFrw6s4

Do you know what is the proper way to map the values?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `@RequestParam` to get query parameter, generally `@RequestBody` is used to get `Json` or any other type of body.

```java
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, value = "/v1/notification")
public ResponseEntity handleNotifications(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> keyValuePairs) { // Chaged @RequestParam & Map
     // Logic
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build(); // To send 200 response
}
```

Let me know once you try.